# What does the "::" mean in "::tolower"?

Tags: c++, string, stl, std, scope-resolution

I've seen code like this:

```
std::string str = "wHatEver";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

And I have a question: what does mean **`::`** before tolower?

and `std::tolower` not works, but `::tolower` works OK

Comment: Technically, it's called the **[scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)**. That should give you a term to begin your search for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Means that it is explicitly using the `tolower` in the global namespace (which is presumably the stdc lib one).

Example:

```
void foo() {
    // This is your global foo
}

namespace bar {
    void foo() {
        // This is bar's foo
    }
}

using namespace bar;

void test() {
    foo();   // Ambiguous - which one is it?
    ::foo(); // This is the global foo()
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I can't understand, you wrote - using namespace bar; why compiler will not use foo from bar? why you need to write bar::foo after using namespace bar; Can you please explain?

Comment: "using namespace bar" means that `foo()` by itself implies `bar::foo()`. However, maybe you meant to use the `foo()` in the global scope? That can also be accessed via `foo()`. So `foo()` could be used for both. Now the compiler isn't sure which one you meant, so you have to specify.

Comment: @EboMike "`foo()` by itself implies `bar::foo()`" is too strong. Name lookup considers `bar::foo` when looking for a match for `foo` (and in this case finds ambiguity with `::foo`)

Answer (score 12):

As to why the `::` is necessary: the standard defines two `tolower`'s,
a function template in `std::`, and a simple function in both `::` and
`std::`.  Depending on which headers have been included (and that includes
headers indirectly included from other headers, which you may not know
about), either one, the other, or both may be visible.  Using `::` ensures
that the older one, from the C standard, is used.  (If the one in `std::`
is considered, the call will be ambiguous, since transform is a template
itself, and the compiler will not be able to deduce the template
arguments.)

While I'm at it, I might mention that using `::tolower` like this is
undefined behavior, at least if plain char is signed.  The input to
`::tolower` is an int, and must be in the range `0`...`UCHAR_MAX`, or `EOF`. If
plain char is signed, some of the characters may have negative
encodings, which results in undefined behavior.  In practice, most
implementations make this work.  For all characters except `0xFF` (ÿ in
Latin 1).  If you're not concerned with portability, some compilers have
a switch to make char unsigned---use it.  Otherwise, write a small
functional object to handle it correctly, either:

```
struct ToLower
{
    char operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return ::tolower( static_cast<unsigned char>(ch) );
    }
};
```

or (better, but significantly more work---only worth it if your using it
a lot), a functional object whose constructor takes a locale (defaulting
to the global locale) and contains a reference to an `std::ctype`, which
it uses for the `tolower` function.  (Of course, if you're really
internationalized, `tolower` probably doesn't have any meaning.  And
you'll be using UTF-8, which is a multi-byte encoding, and doesn't work
with any of the available possibilities.)

Answer (score 4):

Use the version from the global namespace.  (Probably included `<ctypes.h>` and not `<cctypes>` if `std::` doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks. I use Visual C++ 6. So :: says to use tolower from global namespace

Comment: Yes, the other potential overload of tolower are in `<locale>` (I said potential because I don't know how conformant VC++6 is on that point... why use such an old compiler?)

Comment: "why use such an old compiler?" Oh, don't ask)) It's because of very old project

Comment: That's the only one valid reason (But I'd plan for a switch if the project has to be continued).  We see far too many learners still using it.

Answer (score 0):

:: is the global namespace.

```
#include <iostream>

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "::bar" << std::endl;
}

namespace foo
{
    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "foo::bar" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bar();
    foo::bar();
    ::bar();
    using namespace foo;
    foo::bar();
    ::bar(); // bar() would be ambiguous now without ::
}
```

Comment: the comment wasn't clear enough: bar() without :: would be ambiguous

Comment: @Nawaz: Read the comments carefully before downvoting. He says that `::bar()` would be ambiguous without the `::`. In fact, [it is](http://www.ideone.com/Pmi5u).

Comment: @Cody: the comment is edited within 5 mins. Previously it was *"bar() would be ambiguous"*  which is obviously wrong!

Comment: Ironically, the original comment was *ambiguous*! (It wasn't wrong, per se. The current interpretation is perfectly logical, even given the original wording.)

Comment: @Cody: The code was NOT ambiguous, but the comment was saying *"bar() would be ambiguous"*. Is there any confusion now?

Comment: @Cody: But I didn't get the comment in which you said *"Ironically, ..."*. :D

Comment: @Nawaz: It was just a joke. I meant that jhasse's original comment in the source code was ambiguous. It was unclear *which* version of `bar()` he meant would be ambiguous. The first time I read it, I interpreted it correctly, but I could see how you assumed something else entirely.