# What does it mean in C++ when you have a parameter like ::lower?

Tags: c++

On S.O. posts such as [How to convert std::string to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case), I've seen the syntax `::something`, e.g.

```
std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
```

and I'm wondering what that means. I know that std::transform looks for a function or variable named `transform` inside the namespace `std`. But what does the scope operator mean when it doesn't have a first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what does the scope operator mean when it doesn't have a first
>   argument?

It denotes the global namespace.

Consider a simple example. Let;s assume that you defined function `swap`. At the same time you included header `<utility>` that also contains a declaration of `swap`. and after it dirrective using namespace std; To distinguihs them you need to use qualified name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;


void swap( int &x, int &y )
{
    std::cout << "Inside ::swap" << std::endl;
    int tmp = x;
    x = y + 10;
    y = tmp + 10;
}

int main() 
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    std::swap( x, y );

    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;

    x = 1;
    y = 2;

    ::swap( x, y );

    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
x = 2, y = 1
Inside ::swap
x = 12, y = 11
```

In this example `::swap` refers to your function swap defined in the global namespace while `std::swap` refers to standard function `swap` declared in name space `std` in header `<utility>`

If you will write unqualified name

```
swap( x, y );
```

when the compiler will not know which function to call: either standard function `std::swap` or your own function `::swap`

If to exclude directive

```
using namepsace std;
```

and write

```
swap( x, y );
```

then the compiler will call your own function swap.

Now I will explain why in your example with standard algorithm `std::transform` there is used  `::tolower`. The problem is that in C++ there are two functions with name `tolower`. One of which is C standard function declared in header `<cctype>` and other is C++ function declared in header `<locale>`. The C++ Standard allows to place C standard functions in the global namespace. So using name `::tolower` allows the compiler to select the C standard function instead of the C++ function.

Answer (score 5):

```
::tolower
```

means that tolower would be looked up in global namespace

Comment: Meaning it's not inside any namespace?

Comment: @Failed Please see the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270780/what-does-the-mean-in-tolower). `tolower` may exist in the global namespace, `std` or both.

Comment: @FailedSoftwareDeveloper Yes

Answer (score 0):

The [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) function iterates over a sequence and applies a transformation function for each element.

The last argument is a so called **functor**, which may be a function pointer or an object of a class implementing **operator()**. Functor is a concept very widely applied in algorithm-part of std lib.

e.g.: *very useful* function converting all characters to a given character:

```
int testAnywhereInCppCode()
{
    struct ToAnotherChar
    {   
        char _toChar;
        ToAnotherChar( char toChar):_toChar(toChar){}
        char operator()(char c){ return _toChar; }
    };

    ToAnotherChar toAnotherCharConverter('x');

    std::string data = "Hello World";

    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), toAnotherCharConverter);
    return 0;
}

static int testAnywhereInCppCodeCaller = testAnywhereInCppCode();
```

:: means only the global namespace, where [std::toLower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) is implemented.

However std::toLower is only a standard way to make lower-case. You could implement your own (e.g. for a very exotic charset) and use it with std::transform