# ::tolower vs std::tolower difference

Tags: c++, stl, std, stl-algorithm

I have

```
using namespace std;
vector<char> tmp;
tmp.push_back(val);
...
```

Now when I try

```
transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), tmp.begin(), std::tolower);
```

It fails to compile, but this compiles:

```
transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), tmp.begin(), ::tolower);
```

What's the problem with `std::tolower`? It works with one argument, e.g., `std::tolower(56)` compiles. Thanks!

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5270780/ (see the second answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5270970/ )

Comment: @dyp So if `std::lower` needs two arguments, how come `std::tolower(56)` works?

Comment: `std::tolower` is overloaded, there are two functions (one [function from the C library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) taking one argument and [one function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) which takes two arguments) with the name `tolower` in namespace `std`. In the global namespace, if there is anything, then it's only the C library's `tolower` which takes one argument.

Answer (score 4):

`std::tolower` has two overloads and it cannot be resolved for the `UnaryOperation` where the C version `::tolower` does not.

If you want to use the `std::tolower` you can use a lambda as

```
transform(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), tmp.begin(), [](unsigned char c) {return std::tolower(c); });
```

Comment: There also is a unary `std::tolower`, you just need to disambiguate.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, can it be disambiguated via `&std::tolower`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I don't think so, but you can try if you want to. :)

Comment: I believe disambiguation would be like this: `(int(*)(int)) &std::tolower`. Maybe `(int(int)) std::tolower` would work, but probably not.

Comment: @celticminstrel, the former works, with or without the `&`. But I guess the `&` shows the intent more clearly.